# Scaling the Time Independent Schrodinger Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, substitution

What seems like a rather simple question is causing me a lot of difficulty as my base in mathematics is weak.

I want to know how I would scale the Schrodinger equation to find dependence on mass, $m$, given a potential $V(x) = Bx^\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is any even integer (2,4,6,8.....). It is not necessary to solve the entire equation for allowed energies.

I know how to do this for the harmonic oscillator,$V(x) = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$ where we have

$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}kx^2\Psi = E\Psi$

$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + (\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}-\frac{mkx^2}{\hbar^2})\Psi = 0$

Let $\beta = \frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$ and $\alpha^2 = \frac{mk}{\hbar^2}$

If we let $x = \frac{u}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$, then, $\alpha\frac{d^2}{du^2} = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$

And the Schrodinger equation we have in terms of $u$

$\alpha\frac{d^2\Psi}{du^2}+(\beta - \alpha u^2)\Psi=0$

dividing by $\alpha$ gives us

$\frac{d^2\Psi}{du^2}+(\frac{\beta}{\alpha} - u^2)\Psi=0$

from which we can derive the wavefunctions and allowed energies. We end up with

$\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{2mE}{\hbar\sqrt{mk}} = \frac{2E}{\hbar}\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$ if $m,k>0$

where we can discover that energy is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$

Here it is easy to put things into better perspective as we know the solution for the harmonic oscillator.

Setting $\frac{2E}{\hbar}\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} = (2n+1)$, found from the Hermite polynomials, we solve for $E$ as

$E_n = (n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, where it is clear that $E_n \varpropto \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$

Now, for the case where $V(x) = Bx^\gamma$, I get the TISE as

$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} + (\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}-\frac{2mBx^\gamma}{\hbar^2})\Psi = 0$

Now, letting $\beta = \frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$ and $\alpha = \frac{2mB}{\hbar^2}$

$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2}+(\beta - \alpha x^\gamma)\Psi=0$

Here is where I am stuck. Would I make a substitution $u = \frac{x^\gamma}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$? This would cause $dx = \frac{1}{\gamma\sqrt{\alpha}}u^\frac{1}{\gamma-1}du$

So that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} = (\frac{\gamma\sqrt{\alpha}}{u^\frac{1}{\gamma-1}}\frac{d}{du})^2 = \gamma^2\alpha u^\frac{-2}{\gamma-1}\frac{d^2}{du^2}$

Then $\gamma^2 u^\frac{-2}{\gamma-1}\frac{d^2\Psi}{du^2}+(\frac{\beta}{\alpha} -\sqrt{\alpha}u)\Psi=0$

I'm not really sure if this actually helps me. I don't understand how to make meaningful substitutions to arrive at a useful answer. Further, it is not clear to me that even if I scale the TISE, how I would find mass dependence for varying $\gamma$ potential when the solution will be different for each $\gamma$....Wouldn't it be?

Any help appreciated, and sorry for the length.

Comment: Do you want to find the eigenvalues of $\psi \mapsto (\partial_x^2- a x^k)\psi$, or see how they evolve continuously with $a$ ? And don't you have some boundary conditions ? (because otherwise I would expect a continuous spectrum)

Comment: Not necessarily the energy eigenvalues, but only their mass dependence. I showed the example for the harmonic oscillator because it is easy to see the mass dependence. I want to know how to properly scale the Schrödinger equation for given potential in order to produce a meaningful result: dependence on mass

Comment: I don't get the line $\frac{2E}{\hbar} \sqrt{m/k} = 2n+1$ nor the line before, it seems like this is more like a physical interpretation of the eigenvalues (since the mathematical answer is that without boundary condition you have a continuous spectrum)

Comment: I skipped over the math of the series solution to the harmonic oscillator. The 2n+1 comes from the hermite polynomials role in the solution to the harmonic oscillator. I should not need to do this part to find mass dependence for the potential I'm using.